# Variable equal to formula with a declared variable

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

Sorry if the title is confusing, not sure how to phrase this. Basically I want to write a formula which takes a date from a cell specified by the user (myDate) and the address of a starting cell (FirstCell) and based on that:

1. Sets a range (myArea) which starts from the specified cell and extends for a number of cells equal to the number of days in the month and year of the date we selected (numDays).
2. Counts cells in that range that do not have a blank interior (there is no conditional formatting in the sheet) and returns that number.

For example let's say I have the date 1/4/2022 and April in 2022 has 5 days but my table has 6 columns. I want to define a range based on the length of this specific month so that the number of cells which do not have a blank interior is equal to 1 and not 2. And I want this to be reproducible for different months.

[image: Image with an example]

The 2nd point is done and works with a simple user-specified range, the 1st point is the one giving me trouble because I don't want it to return anything in the sheet. The specific issue is setting numDays but there may be other errors I didn't catch - basically I tried to transplant the excel function solution to counting this into VBA but I'm pretty sure I'm getting the syntax wrong and/or this is not doable. Couldn't find anything that would answer my question on here, when I try to use the function it returns #VALUE! in the spreadsheet.

```
Function SPECIALDAYS (FirstCell as Range, myDate as Date)
   Dim myCell as Range
   Dim myArea as Range
   Dim numDays as Integer

   numDays = Application.Evaluate("Day(Eomonth(" & myDate & ",0))")
   Set myArea = Range(FirstCell, FirstCell.Offset(0, numDays-1))
   
   For Each myCell In myArea
      If myCell.Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then
         SPECIALDAYS=SPECIALDAYS+1
      End If
   Next myCell
End Function
```

Comment: The variabe needs to be concatenated with the string otherwise it is just a text: `Application.Evaluate("Day(Eomonth(" & myDate & ",0))")` and `Evaluate` needs the english formula so with `,` as separator not `;`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ oh wow, thank you! Now however it's giving me the same result (31) for every month, even though the same functions when used in the sheet gave the correct length for each date, I'm confused.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some example data you used and how you called the formula on this example data. Also it is unclear what `<condition>` is. We need a [mcve] of your issue with example data to reproduce what is going wrong.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I just did, let me know if it's clearer now or if I should add something more

Comment: @Inez I suggest you update your code to whatever you have currently, looking at old code won't help us help you debug further because we do not know what you did. And what is `<condition>`? You also dim `myCell` as `Integer` but use it as loop? Something don't match...

Comment: @RaymondWu done, body changed to reflect the changes in code. myCell as Integer was a mistake (different computer)

Comment: @Inez Try `For Each myCell In myArea.Cells` I don't have computer to debug now but try stepping through the code and see what is it doing if you have not done so. Make sure to inspect the variables at each step to ensure its doing the right thing.

Comment: So you get that result probably because `myCell.Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142` is never true. Put a `Debug.Print myCell.Interior.ColorIndex` into your loop and check the output in the immediate window.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ 
@RaymondWu
The loop works though, I checked and it would give the correct result if numDays (the number of days in a given month) were correct. So the issue is still somewhere in `numDays = Application.Evaluate("Day(Eomonth(" & myDate & ",0))")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Evaluate` and formula use a pure VBA solution with `WorksheetFunctions`:

```
numDays = Day(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0))
```

See [WorksheetFunction.EoMonth method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.eomonth).